# Could articles be omitted in descriptions of art?

Tags: articles, omissibility, headline-english

Compiling brief descriptions of art objects, is it okay to make do mostly without articles? For instance (about an old coin),

> Eagle under crown; shield featuring Moscow’s coat-of-arms on eagle’s
> chest; scepter and orb in claws.

Another example:

> Armored knight standing right. Sword in right hand, bundle of arrows
> splitting date 16—75 in left.

Comment: Certainly sounds fine to me as an English speaker. Keeps it nice and crisp — similar to news headlines.

Comment: Personal notes that don't even become sentences? You're on your own to skip words you don't value.

Comment: Typical in catalogs, e.g. auction catalogs.